# How can I append a file to input type file?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel

I have a form where the user writes a title and uploads a file from their PC. 
My JS script generates an Excel file and saves it to the PC. How can I append the JS generated file to an file input? For example, I press `tableToExcel` and the file is automatically attached or appended to the file input.

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="title">Title:</label>
  <input id="textthree" type="text" class="form-control" name="title">
</div>
<div class="form-group col-md-3">
  <input id="four" type="file" class="form-control" name="document" accept="application/vnd.ms-excel">
</div>
<div class="form-group col-md-2">
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-success">Send email</button>
</div>
```

```js
var tableToExcel = (function() {
  var uri = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,',
    var link = document.createElement("a");

  link.download = "File.xls";
  link.href = uri + base64(format(template, ctx));

  const blob = new Blob([format(template, ctx)], {
    type: "application/vnd.ms-excel;charset=utf-8"
  });

  saveAs(blob, "File.xls");
}
})();
```

Or how i can pass javascript generated blob file to php function below to save in laravel file storage?

```
 var link = document.createElement("a");
                    link.download = "file.xls";
                    link.href = uri + base64(format(template, ctx));
                    const blob = new Blob([format(template, ctx)], {
                        type: "application/vnd.ms-excel;charset=utf-8"
                    });
                     <?php use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;
                     Storage::disk('local')->put('excel.xls', "blob") ?>

                    saveAs(blob, "file.xls");
                  //  var storagePath = "{!! storage_path() !!}";
                }
            })();
```

Comment: You can not set the value of input type file.

Comment: This is not possible. You cannot programmatically set any content in a file input for various security reasons. What exactly are you trying to achieve with this? There is most likely  a better solution

Comment: is there any roundabout ways? like saving that file to laravel storage, and append that file with form? my goal is for user to send mail with attachment generated from javascript function tabletoexcel()

Comment: In that case you would need to take the file data and upload it to your server, then attach it to an email.